# Multiple domains - subdomains routed to main domain

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I have multiple domains connected to the same DO droplet, with nginx
Let's assume:

```
firstdomain.com
seconddomain.com
```

I would like to set my nginx in a way that, every subdomain will be directed to it's main domain, and it will be reflected in address bar too:

```
subdomain.firstdomain.com ----> firstdomain.com
asldk.firstdomain.com --------> firstdomain.com
test.seconddomain.com --------> seconddomain.com
```

and so on.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to post this answer, for future visitors and for myself (I'm sure I will forget)

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;

    server_name   ~^(?<subdomains>.+\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$;
    if ($subdomains != "") {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://$domain/$1;
    }

    index           index.html;
    root            /etc/nginx/conf.d/404;
}
```

It is almost identical with the solution I accepted, and it has a defined 404 page in conf.d to modify default nginx page.

Comment: Hi, I have a question which seems opposite to your question. My question is [Why did it always show my domain's webpage when I enter my subdomain's address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990084/why-did-it-always-show-my-domains-webpage-when-i-enter-my-subdomains-address). I want to create another different web page with subdomain, but it always route to my main domain. I didn't set the config which you did above.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name   ~^(?<subdomains>.+\.)?(?<domain>[^.]+\.[^.]+)$;
    if ($subdomains != "") {
          rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://$domain/$1;
    }
}
```