# Why did it always show my domain's webpage when I enter my subdomain's address?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a domain - [kongming.io](https://kongming.io/). I want to create a link on the main page of [kongming.io](https://kongming.io/) which links to the subdomain [song.kongming.io](http://song.kongming.io). But when I click that button or type [song.kongming.io](http://song.kongming.io) directly in the explorer, it shows the main website page.

I have been trying for several days, searching tutorials on the internet about [**How To Host Multiple Websites Securely With Nginx And Php-fpm On Ubuntu 14.04**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04). I tried many many many tutorials, but no one works. Even though I did the exactly the same as the tutorial shows.

It looks so easy to set the config, but why did I still fail even I have spent so much time.

Here are some basic informations:

- My domain: [kongming.io](https://kongming.io)
- My subdomain: [song.kongming.io](http://song.kongming.io), which I want to create a link on my main website to link to.
- My host: **digitalocean**
- I am trying to use **nginx** to host multiple sites
- My **digitalocean droplet** settings:

  [image]

And my config settings are the same as the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) shows. FYI, it is showed below.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/song.kongming.io;
index index.html index.htm;

server_name song.kongming.io www.song.kongming.io;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}
```

If you can point out any suggestions or any potential reasons that can cause my problem, I would be really appreciate. I don't know what is wrong with my settings, because I am new to the back end web services, and I really tried a lot. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://kongming.io/ is loading the blog(Kongming's Blog) and when I click on the "Song" button on the site, it is taking me to "http://song.kongming.io/#/welcome" and playing the song - isn't it what you expected?

Comment: What?! Really?! But why cannot I do it on my computer? I mean when I click that  **song** button, it still shows me the same main page. Is there something wrong? I tried it again after I received your comment.@RaviTezu

Comment: And even I click the linkage you provided in your comment, "song.kongming.io/#/welcome", it still shows me the main page... There must be something wrong with my laptop.  Can you suggest some potential mistakes that can cause my problem?

Comment: @RaviTezu I really surprised and appreciated that you can see the **song** page. I have been struggled for many days on this issue. But even now I still cannot see that page on my own. :( Please give me some suggestions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is so tricky. One of my friend told me to clear the cookies and histories of my browser, and I did. And it works!

So this has nothing to do with the nginx config or domain settings. This is because of some bad things remaining in the history of browser.

I don't know why, it just happened.

Comment: Sorry! It was late night when I added that comment. Yes! It could be the browser cache. I am glad that you figured it out :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It was you that let me know that linkage is useful. I am really appreciate that.